# Cannot access Apache test page from the browser

Tags: apache

Something strange is happening. The matter is when I installed **apache2** by using `sudo apt install apache2` the installation got successful without any errors and warnings. When I allowed **"Apache Full"** in ufw, there were also no errors or warnings. I opened the browser on that machine where my apache server is hosted and entered the ip address on the url bar the apache test page became visible which is expected. I got the ip address from the command `ip addr`. localhost was also working.

Here begins the twist:-

When I tried to access the server from another computer with different internet connection   I was unable to access the test page.`Connection refused`in firefox, `can't reach this page` in edge.

Actually I was using my mobile phone's internet *usb tethered* with the server computer.
When I just turned off the internet connection ***I was able to access the test page on browser of server computer and also on my mobile phone browser***, but not in any other device.

Please help me out of this situation. Thanks in advance.

> I use Kubuntu with backports ppa enabled and kde plasma 5.22(latest).

Comment: ufw allow 80   ufw allow 443

Comment: @MikeMoy **I checked that before** in `netstat` and done that again after you said. The problem still persists.

Comment: Are you sure your typing the correct address in when trying to access, some devices will default to https when you are trying to reach a http website

Comment: @MikeMoy yes I double checked the address on the url bar i.e, the ip address of server. I also copy pasted through kde connect because at one time I thought I was wrong in typing the correct address. This is a very strange problem.

Comment: the IP address that you are referring to, is it an external IP address ? Also is it an IPv4 address or is it an IPv6 address

Comment: @MikeMoy That is ipv4 address that `192.16x.xx.xxx`

Answer (score 1):

The IPv4 address that you are referring to "192.16x.xx.xxx" is an IP address on your local network. By default it is not visible to devices that are not on your local network i.e. if you try connect to your server with a device that is not connected to your local network using "192.16x.xx.xxx" it will not connect. A mobile phone using a 4G connection is not on your local network, a mobile phone connected to the same wifi network as your server computer is on the local network. Note it goes without saying that if your server computer firewall is blocking connections that even devices on your home network will not be able to connect to "192.16x.xx.xxx"

Comment: pls tell me the **commands** and I will edit the question with the screenshots of results I got after running those commands so you can **troubleshoot** them better

Comment: also as u said the device that are connected to the the local network have access to the server computer's apache. That is actually not happening. I am using **usb tethering** from a **4g phone** for giving the server computer internet access(as I mentioned in the question). That phone and the server computer has access to the test page but any other device that takes internet connection from that usb tethered phone using wifi hotspot is unable to access the test page. Why it is so? After your answer I checked one more time but result is the same.

Comment: your server computer does not need internet access for Apache to be able to host on your local network.

Comment: Ooo, thanks for awaring me about that. Then what should I do make the test page accessible over internet? I want make my own server. I saw a video in youtube of where the performer is creating his vps in digitalocean. So thought can I do that in my own pc for study and experiment purposes.

Comment: By default with IPv4 your address "192.16x.xx.xxx" is not visible to devices not on you local network. 
The IPv4 address range "192.16x.xx.xxx" is reserved for devices on your local network. 
If you google 'what is my IP address' you will see your external IP address this is the address that can be used to access the server over the internet.
You would need to look into port forwarding if you want to make your computer server accessible to devices not on your local network.
Read up on IPv4 so that you have a basic understanding of the underlying technology you are trying to use.

Comment: Thanks I will definitely check and report you about the progress.